# SSRS "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportServerException: The report execution has expired or cannot be found" on Macintosh and IOS devices

Tags: ios, asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

We're using the SSRS ReportViewer control on an ASP.NET WebForms site.  We keep getting this error:

> "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportServerException: The report
>   execution j1ouqgbqxj2x1o550udofz3w has expired or cannot be found"

(the *j1ouqgbqxj2x1o550udofz3w* value varies).

We are only getting this error from site visitors on Macs, iPads and iPhones using the Safari browser.  The vast majority of our visitors users are on Windows machines. We have visitors on Android devices but they don't get the error.

The page in question is using 4 SSRS ReportViewer controls to display reports that each contains one chart (the 4 report controls are shown side-by-side in a 4-column table).

We actually have two pages that display the 4 charts in exactly the same way but with one exception: the page that is getting the error is rendering the table containing the SSRS charts inside a DIV (id="divGraphs") that has is initially styled **display:none**.  The DIV is made visible when the user clicks a link calling the JQuery command `$("#divGraphs").slideToggle(500);` It's re-hidden when the link is clicked again.

The page that has the initially hidden SSRS controls (the one getting the error) is linked to from the one that has the same controls but isn't getting the error.  Visitors using Safari only occasionally get the error (I've tested using an iPad and hit the two pages several times before the error was triggered - and I couldn't determine what, if anything, I did to trigger it).

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running SSRS 2005?

Comment: We're using SSRS 2012.  The version on the ReportViewer control itself is 12.0.0.0.